# animate fires callback before complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use animate function

```
    var square = $('<div class="square"></div>');
    $('body').append(square);

    square.css({
        'background-color': 'red',
        'top': '10px',
        'left': '10px'
    }).animate({
        left: left + 'px',
        top: top + 'px'
    }, {
        duration: 400,
        complete: callback
    });
```

its firing the callback before it actually completes

I had to do a workaround

in the callback function I use setTimeout to have it wait 400 seconds. But why can't I have animate call the callback function when it trully completes?

Comment: Must be something else causing the problem because it [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/s6e12fts/). Also, you don't need the `+ 'px'`

Answer (score 0):

Pass completion callback as a third argument

```
square.css({
    'background-color': 'red',
    'top': '10px',
    'left': '10px'
}).animate({
    left: left + 'px',
    top: top + 'px'
}, 400, callback);
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: doesn't work. it still fires the callback before completing

Comment: His syntax is fine he's using the [`animate(properties, options)`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) signature.

Comment: @BrownLimie is it reproducable in fiddle/plunker?